# Advertencia al instalar paquetes de python?

Tags: python, pip

He estado intentando descargar librerias necesarias para mis programas el problema que tengo es que cuando descargo la libraría que sea me da el siguiente error

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -yautogui (c:\users\0.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages)
```

He intentado lo siguiente:

- Actualizar PIP
- Actualizar librerías

Agradecería de antemano que me ayuden con mi situación ya que no se que hacer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aparentemente existe una carpeta con el nombre dañado dentro de la ruta `c:\users\0.0\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages` con un nombre no válido y cada vez que pip intenta realizar alguna acción te avisa de ello.

Entra en site-packages y comprueba si por algún casual se ha quedado alguna carpeta con el nombre `-yautogui` seguido probablemente de algún número. Si es así prueba a borrarlas y debería desaparecer el mensaje.

Comment: Me bastaría moverla de carpeta ?

Comment: Lo he movido de carpeta y se me ha quitado la advertencia, pero aun tengo una duda ¿En algun momento haber elimando/movido esas carpeta me traerá un error ya sea en python IDLE o al usar pip? @César Gonzalez

Comment: Mover la carpeta -yautoguiXXXX a otra ruta? En teoría sí pero... para qué querrías hacerlo? En site-packages deberían estar únicamente los paquetes instalados en el entorno :/

Comment: No debería generarte ningún error. Es más que probable que tengas instalado el paquete pyautogui correctamente que es el que debería usarse. El que has eliminado/movido no se podría importar de ninguna manera

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio me sacaste de un gran susto : )

Answer (score 4):

A mi también me mostraba estos mensajes de advertencia para python 3.9.7, lo que hice fue ir a la carpeta:
`C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages` y eliminar los archivos que iniciaran con `~`
Esto claro ejecutando la terminal como Administrador.